# Spring Boot Application Failed to start

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am currently new to spring boot and I am having trouble in resolving the error ,
I would be glad if anyone could help me out

This is the Error I am getting
This the Complete Exception

My Dialect is InnoDb

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mediaocean.hotelproject.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table review add constraint FKi0ly7ivbh8ijdgoi7cwtuoavt foreign key (hotel_id) references hotel (hotel_id)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table 'hotelproject.#sql-95c_2d' (errno: 150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelproject
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Hotel Model Code
It has a OneToMany Mapping To Review Model And ManyToOne Mapping To City Model

```
package com.mediaocean.hotelproject.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Hotel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int hotelId;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String zip;

//  private int city_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="city_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private City city;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Review> review;

    public Hotel() {
        super();
    }

//  public Hotel(int hotelId, String hotelName, String hotelAddress, String hotelZip) {
//      this.hotelId = hotelId;
//      this.name = hotelName;
//      this.address = hotelAddress;
//      this.zip = hotelZip;
//  }
//  
    public int getHotelId() {
        return hotelId;
    }

//  public int getCityId() {
//      return city_id;
//  }

    public String getHotelName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getHotelAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getHotelZip() {
        return zip;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the full expection?

Comment: your line "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update" is issuing a DDL update upon startup so I'd look at your DDL scripts..

Comment: share your Hotel model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems hibernate is trying to alter table which is violating some constraint, simply drop all your tables or at least the table with the problem and change ddl to create this will solve the issue but you will lose your data.

If you do not want to lose your data you can either specify a new table using @Table annotation but again the old table will be ignored and data will be lost or you can alter your table manually.